# react native TouchableNativeFeedback ripple is too slow

Tags: android, react-native

Here is my code. It produces very 
slow ripple effect.

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback
                     delayPressIn={1}
                     background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('#777')}
                       onPress={() => this._navigateTo(item.route)}>
</TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

Comment: have you found any solution to this please update???

Answer (score 2):

As per [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3958#issuecomment-154658193), all you need to do is set the `delayPressIn` attribute of the `TouchableNativeFeedback` component to `0`:

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback background={TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()} delayPressIn={0}>
</TouchableNativeFeedback>
```